# typescript gives me error when i try to pass mapped object as children

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've created a component that map an object and on the interface i pass reach child | react children, but it gives me the following error: `Type 'Element[]' is not assignable to type 'ReactChild | ReactChildren'. Type 'Element[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

i saw on stack overflow that maybe wrapping the component with fragment (<>) will help but it give me the same typescript error.

The code:

```js
const DashboardSettings = () => {
    const { scene } = useAppSelector((state) => state.plotly);
    return (
        <Root>
            {scene?.aspectratio && (
                <BasicCard title="Aspect Ration">
                    {
                        Object.keys(scene?.aspectratio).map((x) => (
                            <>
                                <div>{x}</div>
                            </>
                        ))
                    }
                </BasicCard>
            )}
        </Root>
    );
};
```

EDIT:
The typescript error happens in  when i send it children as an object, but when I remove the Object.keys and put a regular div it works fine.

Card.tsx:

```
export interface ICard {
    title: string;
    children: ReactChild | ReactChildren;
}

const BasicCard = ({ children, title }: ICard) => (
    <Card sx={{ minWidth: 275 }}>
        <Typography>
            {title}
        </Typography>
        <CardContent>
            {children}
        </CardContent>
        <CardActions>
            <Button size="small">Learn More</Button>
        </CardActions>
    </Card>
);
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What type is `x` in your map?

Comment: @casr x is string.

Comment: I really doubt if `x` is a string. Can you double check by logging or debugging?

Comment: yeah my bad, it's a number. 
scene: {
  aspectratio: {
   x: 4.8,
   y: 6,
   z: 1.2,
  },

Comment: Given that shape `x` in the map function is a string as it relates to the keys of the object `scene.aspectratio` (i.e. 'x', 'y' and 'z'). What line is the error that you receive occurring in the snippet that you've listed?

Comment: the error happen inside the<BasicCard>
I send there an object.map

Comment: try --- children: ReactText | ReactText[]; If it doesnt work, try to map x as string

Comment: @SlothOverlord unfortunately same error:
`Type 'Element[]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | ReactChildren | ReactText[]'.
  Type 'Element[]' is not assignable to type 'ReactText[]'.
    Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactText'.
      Type 'ReactElement<any, any>' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)
`

Comment: Oh, I missed the div element there, ignore my previous comment. Try either removing the fragment as you don't need it there, or set children as Element | Element[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem...
The child type should've been ReactNode,

```js
export interface ICard {
    title: string;
    children: ReactChild | ReactChildren | ReactNode;
}
```